# C# windows store/winRT Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store

I have an app with a button to navigate back to the start page. First time I use it no problems what so ever, but if I then navigate into the app and use the back button a second time the app hangs on this line

```
global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => new App());
```

in this file

```
App.g.i.cs
```

which is an auto-generated file. if I set a breakpoint on that line I get the following error when I mouse over

```
Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack.
```

I tried using both

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(StartPage));
```

and

```
Frame.GoBack();
```

in the event handler for the button to navigate back.
I couldn't find anything that seemed like the same problem from googling nor searching on Stack overflow

Comment: It is supposed to hang on that line.  If it didn't then your app would immediately terminate.  You are just looking at the wrong thread, use Debug + Windows + Threads to pick the correct one.

Comment: Solved. I had created a deadlock between UI thread and one of the Async ones. and you are correct.